# How do I rearrange excel values? Sorry hard to explain without example

Tags: excel-2003

It is difficult to explain in words, so I have to show it instead:

Basically I have this:

[image]

And I want it to look like this:

[image]

Is there a formula that will let me create something like column B?
There's more countries than this in the actual excel (2003) file, and I cannot do this manually, as I'm planning to use data in column B to link to another formula in column C.  Ultimately I want to be able to enter data manually elsewhere, and have column A filter the relevant countries (it already does this), column B to arrange them properly like the second image file, and column C to use that to calculate other stuff.  I'm not very good at explaining so if I'm not making sense please say so.

EDIT: I'm trying to show this in words as well, but I don't really know how to format this, so sorry in advance

So basically I have this:

```
A ------ B ------ C

Japan  
US  
Germany



Indonesia



Malaysia

Vietnam
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
A      B       C
       Japan  
       US
       Germany
       Indonesia      
       Malaysia
       Vietnam
```

Sorry I know the formatting is bad I have no idea how I did the second part, but basically in the first one there's gaps in between countries in column A (e.g. A1 - Japan, A2 - US, A5 - Germany, A11 - Indonesia, A12 - Vietnam etc.) and I want column B to be B1 - Japan, B2 US, B3 - Germany, B4 - Indonesia, B5 - Vietnam ... does that make sense?

Comment: Can u upload as image? Access to the URL is blocked.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I need to have 10 reputations (I think?) first.  What do you mean by blocked, maybe I can do something about that?

Comment: Ok, looks like images have been added, but by someone else?  Thanks L42

Comment: Still blocked! :( Can you post your requirement to something like data as in 

           | A     |   B
    ----------------------
    1      |Product|  Total
    -----------------------
    2      | A     |   4
    ----------------------
    3      | B     |  11
    ----------------------
    4      | C     |  1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply what you want [Remove Blanks](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2007/09/16/excel-remove-blank-cells/). Credits to Oscar Cronquist.
If the link is somehow broken, you use this formula in B1. Copy or auto-fill to other cells.
Change the range to suit.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$30, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$30), "", ROW($A$1:$A$30)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$30))+1), ROW(A1))),"")`

This is an array formula entered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Edit1:** *ISERROR* Equivalent

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$30, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$30), "", ROW($A$1:$A$30)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$30))+1), ROW(A1)))),"",INDEX($A$1:$A$30, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$30), "", ROW($A$1:$A$30)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$30))+1), ROW(A1))))`

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I _think_ this will work, but IFERROR function doesn't exist in Excel 2003, so can I replace IFERROR with IF(ISERROR) and keep the rest?

Comment: Erm sorry I put this down: =if(iserror(Index($A$1:$A$30,Small(if(isblank($A$1:$A$30),"",Row($A$1:$A$30)-min(row(A1:A30))+1),row(A1))),""))    But I got the "you've entered too many arguments" error.. Did I do this wrong, or is there another problem?   Sorry I don't know how to format this properly

Comment: @user3724612 See my edit for the ISERROR equivalent.

Comment: oops sorry didn't see that.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: erm sorry again it works for the first row, but it doesn't seem to work for the others?  http://imgur.com/YAmRHOQ

Comment: @user3724612 Ctrl+Shift+Enter please. Not the usual way of entering the formula by enter key. You need the CSE combination.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work Before: http://imgur.com/sr5zbGp  After:  http://imgur.com/TplIdmc  The only thing it seems to do is stretch out the formula in the formula bar, and nothing else :(

Comment: @user3724612 I uploaded a [test file](http://wikisend.com/download/316560). See the link.

Comment: Ctrl+shift+enter still doesn't seem to work :X  Copying from the sample file directly seems to work, though.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3724612 Strange. Try re-starting your excel maybe. But at least it did work by copying from file to file.

Comment: Final post:  I'm an idiot, I just needed to have the cursor in the formula before pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter...