# Removing blank space in excel, not changing range correctly?

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I asked about how to remove blanks yesterday (in an excel 2003 file), and received a great response, along with a sample:

http://wikisend.com/download/497760/Sample%201.xls

when I tried it on my own, with a different range, I didn't get the result I expected:

http://wikisend.com/download/439730/Sample%202.xls

where did I go wrong here?

post from yesterday:

[How do I rearrange excel values? Sorry hard to explain without example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134229/how-do-i-rearrange-excel-values-sorry-hard-to-explain-without-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it correctly. However *ISBLANK* function fails because the data you're working with are not really blank but zero length strings.So *ISBLANK* always evaluates to FALSE and thus just mimics how your data is arranged.

To make the formula work, replace your *ISBLANK* formula

`IF(ISBLANK($E$5:$E$80),"",ROW($E$5:$E$80)-MIN(ROW($E$5:$E$80))+1)`

with below formula:

`IF(E$5:E$80<>"",ROW(E$5:E$80)-MIN(ROW(E$5:E$80))+1,"")`

Adding it to the formula:

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(E$5:E$80,SMALL(IF(E$5:E$80<>"",ROW(E$5:E$80)-MIN(ROW(E$5:E$80))+1,""),ROW(A1)))),"",INDEX(E$5:E$80,SMALL(IF(E$5:E$80<>"",ROW(E$5:E$80)-MIN(ROW(E$5:E$80))+1,""),ROW(A1))))`

This will produce your desired result.

Comment: It works!  You are amazing thanks!  I spent a couple of hours trying to dissect this formula and didn't really get anywhere so this was really helpful.

Comment: @user3724612 Zero length strings are result of formulas, or a copy paste values wherein the value came from `=""`. The current formula should work even with formula returning a blank as `""`.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll keep that in mind for future uses as well thanks!